# Discount amount reflect properly into Order review page but added discount not taken over to Final order placed

Tags: magento-1.7, discount, coupon

I am trying to apply custom discount for an order through my custom extension. I am showing custom textbox for adding coupon code and after that I fetch discount amount for that code from API and trying to apply for respective order.

Error : Using below code my discount show on order review page but it not taken over to Final order placed.Final order shows no discount.

## I put below function in my controller .

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class Company_ModuleName_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {

```
public function customcouponPostAction() {
    $quote = $this->_getQuote();
    $quoteid = $quote->getId();
    $discountAmount = 20;

    if ($quoteid) {

        if ($discountAmount > 0) {

            $total = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
            $quote->setSubtotal(0);
            $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

            $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
            $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

            $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
            $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


            $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual() ? ('billing') : ('shipping');
            foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

                $address->setSubtotal(0);
                $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $address->collectTotals();

                $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );

                $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

                $quote->save();

                $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                        ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                        ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                        ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                        ->save();



                if ($address->getAddressType() == $canAddItems) {
                    //echo $address->setDiscountAmount; exit;
                    $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount() - $discountAmount);
                    $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);
                    $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() - $discountAmount);
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);
                    if ($address->getDiscountDescription()) {
                        $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount() - $discountAmount));
                        $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription() . ', Custom Discount');
                        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount() - $discountAmount));
                    } else {
                        $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
                        $address->setDiscountDescription('Custom Discount');
                        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
                    }
                    $address->save();
                }//end: if
            } //end: foreach
            //echo $quote->getGrandTotal();

            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
                $rat = $item->getPriceInclTax() / $total;
                $ratdisc = $discountAmount * $rat;
                $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount() + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
                $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount() + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();
            }
        }
    }

    $this->loadLayout(false);
    $review = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('roots')->toHtml();
    $response['review'] = $review;
    //$this->_goBack();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
}
```

}

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `$quote->save();` just after the `foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {` loop.